# Getting null for getElementById() in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am calling a javascript function from jsp as follows

```
<td align="left"><b><input type="text"  id="ename" size="30"  onblur="javascript:showFormDetails()" /></b>
```

I have specified this function in a seperate js file as

```
function showFormDetails()
 {

  alert("Inside showForm details");    

  var fname=document.getElementById("ename");   

      alert(fname);
}
```

now when i print the fname using alert i am getting only null as value...where am i going wrong?Can anyone plz help...

Comment: Are you waiting for the DOM to be loaded?

Comment: use `value` in the end. `var fname=document.getElementById("ename").value;`

Comment: Your code works [as it is](http://jsfiddle.net/HUyY8/), in any browser... @ikaros I guess no need for that, the retrieved `id` is the id of the element which triggers the event.

Comment: It seems like your example works http://jsfiddle.net/AGcqW/

Comment: Have you checked your code for error in your browser debug utility (like firebug)?

Comment: Teemu, AFAIK `getElementById` searches in the DOM. To retrieve the id of the element that triggered the event, you should look in `this` or in the event object.

Comment: @ikaros45 Yes it does, but it doesn't make any difference here. You can [search that part](http://jsfiddle.net/qDhxY/) of the DOM, which is ready...

Comment: Three warnings: 1) if there are OTHER fields with ID=ename, your code may fail; 2) Do not attempt to focus something inside the alert when using blur to show the alert 3) the `javascript:` psedoprotocol/label in ONLY needed if the first script on the page is not JavaScript and you are in the IE browser

Comment: The example given in the question does not actually do what you says it does. You do get a non-null value.

Answer (score 3):

try this...

```
var fname=document.getElementById("ename").value;
```

Comment: What is the problem with the original code? Why does your code fix that problem?

Comment: @Tibos added .value at the last

Comment: How does this help, if gEBI returns `null`? You just would get a reference error.

Comment: The actual problem is called before DOM loading.

Comment: @ling.s No, it's not, the retrieved `id` is the id of the element which triggers the event.

Comment: @Teemu better see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cjramki/HUyY8/2/

Comment: @Teemu this fiddle is using this answer http://jsfiddle.net/cjramki/HUyY8/3/

Comment: See the fiddle , at the left side you can check with `onload` which doesn't work

Comment: because, onblur event already called in text box.

Comment: The point is, that OP is getting `null` from  `document.getElementById("ename")`. It doesn't help, if you try to read `null.value`! Guys, please read the question!

Comment: @CJRamki Better see what fiddle?  The one you posted shows HTMLInputElement, not `null`

Answer (score 0):

It returns the value of the text field.

```
var fname=document.getElementById("ename").value;
```

[check here](http://jsfiddle.net/HUyY8/1/)

Comment: before post your answer check previous answers. This was already posted here http://stackoverflow.com/a/21258108/2567813

Comment: How does this help, if gEBI returns `null`? You just would get a reference error.